# Unicode, decoding and encoding problems caused by Microsoft Translator API

Tags: python, unicode, microsoft-translator

Error message occurs such as:

```
Internal Server Error: /Translator/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Project\Reservation\Translator\views.py", line 72, in getParams
    content = request.POST['content'].decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
  File "D:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
[05/Oct/2013 23:32:51] "POST /Translator/ HTTP/1.1" 500 65244
Internal Server Error: /Translator/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Project\Reservation\Translator\views.py", line 72, in getParams
    content = request.POST['content'].decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
  File "D:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code follows bellow:

```
def get_access_token():
    post_data = urllib.urlencode({'client_id':client_id,'client_secret':client_secret, 'scope':ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE, 'grant_type':ACCESS_TOKEN_GRANT_TYPE })
    token_data = json.loads(requests.post(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,data=post_data).content)
    access_token = token_data["access_token"]

    return access_token

def detect(access_token,detect_text):

    headers = {'Authorization': 'bearer'+ ' ' + access_token}

    detect_url_all = DETECT_URL + "?" + urllib.urlencode({'text':detect_text})
    detect_language = requests.get(detect_url_all,headers=headers).content[3:]

    return detect_language


def Translator(text,orignal,access_token):

    headers = {'Authorization': 'bearer'+ ' ' + access_token}

    translation_ars = {
            'text': text,
            'to': 'zh',
            'from': orignal
        }

    transate_url_all = TRANSLATE_URL + "?" + urllib.urlencode(translation_ars)
    result = requests.get(transate_url_all,headers=headers).content
    return result

def getParams(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Junk(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            content = request.POST['content'].decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
            country = detect(get_access_token(),content)
            result = Translator(content,country,get_access_token())
            return render_to_response('Translator/translate.html',{'result':result})
    else:
        form = Junk()
    return render_to_response('Translator/index.html',{'form': form})
```

First, I want to detect the language of a text first. My program can't get to know what the text's coding is, so I can't make a decoding or encoding.

Comment: So your problem is: You can't retrieve the encoding of the text?

Comment: Thanks for your response! yes, I don't know how to process the type of coding of the text ,such as Russian,portuguese,Chinese and so on.

Comment: Isn't the encoding always Unicode? What do you need to convert it to?

Comment: Yes,so I must covert them to utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is very simple, you're using the wrong method. Use `result.encode` (instead of `result.decode`) method to encode it to `utf-8` encoding.

Sorry for my late answer.

Comment: @alKaamili,Thanks for your answer. it may be a mistake for my code.I modified the codes. I just wanna initialize the text got from the froms to 'utf-8'. Now I only can translate English.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates `request.POST['content']` was already Unicode. `.decode('utf-8')` expects the object to be a byte string, so an implicit `.encode('ascii')` is used to turn Unicode string into a byte string.  since it is already a Unicode string and you seem to want a UTF-8 byte string, all you need is:

```
content = request.POST['content'].encode('utf-8')
```

`request` must have been passed to `getParams` as a Unicode string, but that part of your code isn't present.

If you have further problems, this example might help: https://gist.github.com/dpapathanasiou/2790853